# How many cpu sockets does Windows 10 support?

Tags: cpu, windows-10

I would like to build a new computer (it's been 7 years since the last one). Does Windows 10 support more than one [CPU socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_socket)?

Comment: Yes. As an example, will Windows 10 support, 2 E5-2699 Xeon processors?

Comment: Taht would total 2 sockets and 36 cores I believe.

Comment: I'm not sure if this information is documented anywhere yet. Perhaps ask on the Microsoft forums, this user was able to get the information for Windows 7: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/what-versions-of-windows-7-support-multiple/00126990-d259-4bb4-9599-3d0566ca0282 It will probably depend on the edition of Windows as well: Home, Pro, Enterprise

Comment: One socket for Windows 10 Home. Two sockets for Windows 10 Pro, Enterprise, and Education. Any number of cores is supported.

Comment: I see no reason Microsoft would change this limit that has been around for years. It use to be [printed on the old COA stickers in the XP days](http://dimeye.com/?page=windows-xp-home-oem-product-key)

Answer (score 8):

Depends on windows variant and architecture. Win10 Pro x64 supports 2 sockets, 256 logical cores and up to 512GB RAM

For more sockets you need to get a "server" os

There's an answer from ms insider [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_upgrade/windows-10-versions-cpu-limits/905c24ad-ad54-4122-b730-b9e7519c823f?auth=1)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2017/12/15/windows-10-pro-workstations-power-advanced-workloads/

I was looking for the answer to the same question yet find the answer right here.
Btw, I noticed that windows 10 enterprise build 10240 recognized only 2 CPU sockets. But it does recognize 4 CPU sockets after I update it to build 1903.